# Spring Batch - RepositoryItemReader read param from ExecutionContext

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have Spring Batch job where I am passing some values between two stpes. I set the value in Job Context in Step1 and now trying to read from RepositoryItemReader in Step2. There is @BeforeStep method where I am able to read value set in context. But I am setting up my repository along with method name and args in @PostConstruct annotated method which is executed before @BeforeStep annotated method.

What is the best way to read param in ReposiotryItem from JobExecution Context?

```
@Component
@JobScope
public class MyItemReader extends RepositoryItemReader<Scan> {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;
    private Integer lastIdPulled = null;

    public MyItemReader() {
        super();        
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void initializeValues(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        Integer value = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getInt("lastIdPulled");
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>> last_pulled_id = " + value);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        final Map<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
        sorts.put("id", Direction.ASC);
        this.setRepository(this.repository);
        this.setSort(sorts);
        this.setMethodName("findByGreaterThanId"); // You should sepcify the method which  
                   //spring batch should call in your repository to fetch 
                   // data and the arguments it needs needs to be  
                   //specified with the below method.
        List<Object> methodArgs = new ArrayList<Object>();
        if(lastIdPulled== null || lastIdPulled<=0 ){
            lastScanIdPulled = 0;
        }
        methodArgs.add(lastIdPulled);
        this.setArguments(methodArgs);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reader needs to be @StepScoped instead of @JobScoped.  Even though you're accessing the job context, the value is not available in the context until the previous step finishes.  If you @StepScope your reader then it won't initialize until the step it is part of starts up and the value is available.

Another option is to construct the reader as a @Bean definition in a @Configuration file but the idea is the same.  This uses SpEL for late binding.

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    // Your item reader will get autowired into this method
    // so you don't have to call it
    @Bean
    public Step myStep(MyItemReader myItemReader) {
        //build your step
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MyItemReader myItemReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext[partitionKey]}") Integer lastIdPulled) {
        MyItemReader reader = new MyItemReader();
        // Perform @PostConstruct tasks
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Comment: First option is still going to have same problem since @ BeforeScope is executed after @ PostConstruct. In 2nd option, how will one call myItemReader method while building the step. When I do myItemReader(), it complains about missing args but arg should be autowired based on Value annotation

Comment: Make your bean implement InitializingBean and use the afterPropertiesSet() method to do the initialization you're doing in @PostConstruct method.

Comment: Updated my code to show an example of how you can still reference that bean.  I believe you can also just pass null as the parameter and Spring will use late-binding to set it correctly during the step.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to solve your problem, and mine, without having to create a @Bean definition in @Configuration file and without using @PostConstruct.

Instead of using @PostConstruct, just set them in the constructor of the class and in your @BeforeStep set the arguments as shown below:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class MyItemReader extends RepositoryItemReader<Scan> {


@Autowired
public MyItemReader(MyRepository myRepository) {
    super();
    this.setRepository(MyRepository myRepository);
    this.setMethodName("findByGreaterThanId");

    final Map<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
    sorts.put("id", Direction.ASC);
    this.setSort(sorts);      
}

@BeforeStep
public void initializeValues(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    Integer value = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getInt("lastIdPulled");
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>> last_pulled_id = " + value);

    List<Object> methodArgs = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if(lastIdPulled== null || lastIdPulled<=0 ){
       lastScanIdPulled = 0;
    }
    methodArgs.add(lastIdPulled);
    this.setArguments(methodArgs);
}
}
```